# Metric equivalence

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I have that $E=[0,1]$ and $d'(x,y)=|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|$ and i want to prove that $d'$ and the usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ are not equivalent in the metric sense.

I proved easely that $d(x,y)\leq 2 d'(x,y)$ but i don't find an example witch give me that we can't prove  for a positive $\alpha,$ that $$\alpha~ d'(x,y)\leq d(x,y) $$ Pease help me

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y = 0$. Assume there is $\alpha$ so that

$$
\alpha \sqrt x \leq x
$$

for all $x$. This would mean that $\alpha \leq \sqrt x$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: where is the contradiction please ?

Comment: what is $\inf_{x \in [0,1]} \sqrt x$?

Comment: it is $0$ , so the contradiction is that $\alpha$ must be negative !

Comment: Yes, good work! Or said another way, there is no positive $\alpha$ that can satisfy this condition.

Comment: In the case $x=0$ we can't do this ? we can't say that $\alpha \leq \sqrt{x}$ !!!

Comment: That is correct; if these metrics were equivalent, there would be some **positive** $\alpha$ so that $\alpha \leq \sqrt x$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. But $\sqrt 0 = 0$ so clearly such an $\alpha$ does not exist.

Comment: But we can say directly that $\alpha \sqrt{x}\leq x=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}$ then $\alpha\leq \sqrt{x}$ we can't devide $\sqrt{x}$ from $x$ if it is equal to 0 ?

Comment: This is where the infimum comes in. Rather than set $x = 0$, we can observe that for *any* positive $x$, we must have $\alpha \leq \sqrt x$. Are there any positive numbers that are smaller than every other positive numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Set $y=0$, then you want to prove
$$\alpha\sqrt x=\alpha\,d'(x,0)\le d(x,0)=x\iff \sqrt x(\sqrt x-\alpha)\ge 0,$$
which clearly fails for $\sqrt x<\alpha$.

---

A more advanced way of seeing it is that for $f(x)=\sqrt x$ we have $f'_+(x)=+\infty$, so $f$ can't be Lipschitz from the right at $0$.

Comment: if $\sqrt{x}>\alpha $ we obtaine what ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou That's irrelevant, you need your inequality to hold for **all** $x$.

Comment: you do a typo $\sqrt{x}\geq \alpha$

Comment: @Vrouvrou ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: $\alpha \sqrt{x}\leq x \Longleftrightarrow \sqrt{x}(\alpha-\sqrt{x}) $ it impliese that $ \alpha-\sqrt{x}<0$ i.e $\alpha <\sqrt{x}$

Comment: @Vrouvrou YES, THAT'S THE CONTRADICTION BECAUSE $\sqrt x$ CAN BE SMALLER THAN $\alpha$.

Comment: we can say $\alpha <\sqrt{x}$ for all x then $\alpha<\inf\sqrt{x} =0$ contradiction

Comment: @Vrouvrou Yes if you replace $<$ by $\le$.